# game(directx) doesn't react on c++ keybd_event

Tags: c++, keyboard

I need help with solving one thing.

I write for fun one project to take control of Hugo game, I want to simulate keyboard in it. Despite simulating keyboard in c++ is easy thing, I don't know why Hugo doesn't react.

When I simulate with keyb_event:

```
keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

as well as when I send it with SendInput:

```
INPUT ip;

ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.wScan = 0;
ip.ki.time = 0;
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
ip.ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT;

ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Or SendMessage:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RIGHT, 0);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_RIGHT, 0);
```

In all those cases, in notepad, cursor moves correctly, but Hugo still doesn't react.

I checked with GetForegroundWindow and GetClassName that Hugo is correctly on foreground. Forcing with SetFocus and SetActiveWindow  didn't changed anything also.

I can't tell much about Hugo, so here is anything that I know for sure: it's old game, it opens in full screen, catalog "DIRECTX" suggests that it was written with DirectX and actually this is all I know.

Currently I don't have more ideas, what to do to send keyboard press to that game. Do you have any clues?

Answer (score 0):

It probably use DirectInput. Try using scancode for SendInput.

Example:

```
INPUT ip = {0};

ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.wScan = 73; // left arrow
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT)); // left arrow pressed

ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT)); // left arrow released
```

Comment: Nope, still the same :(